# React setLoading onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this function.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);
  
  try {
      await axios.get('/something');
  } catch {
      setLoading(false);
  };
 
 };
```

And I want to setLoad onClick.
However, doing that I also rerender the page, and I lost all my form data.
Putting inside the try will not cause the expected effect.

Tried with useRef, but that doesn't make the form data disappear but neither the loading appear, 'cause again: the page doesn't rerender.

Any solution?

Comment: If you are submitting data you should use `post`, not `get`. What do you _do_ with the data you are submitting? (Could you share the form?) And are you saving that form data to state?

Comment: Please share the whole component, where you call `handleSubmit()`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `event` as function parameter

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);
  
  try {
      await axios.get('/something');
  } catch {
      setLoading(false);
  };
 
};
```